# How to remove an empty line before return in condition line with only few lines?

Tags: phpstorm

When in PhpStorm 2023 I make auto reformat of code, I got an empty line before return in condition line:

```php
if (empty($categoryName)) {
    $this->error('Category Name is not provided');

    return;
}
```

If there is an option to set an empty line only when there are, say, 5 lines of code in this block of code? I do not need an empty line in such small block of code.

Comment: There is no option in PhpStorm for the minimal number of lines before the `return` statement. It's simply either ON or OFF for adding the black line there. **P.S.** Maybe external formatters can do that? This way you can turn off the built-in formatter and only use the external one (since next 2024.1 version only AFAIK)